# How can I get a pro-apis key for test?

Tags: transactions, transfer, api, websocket, solscan

How can I get a pro-apis key for test? I want to use these apis : https://pro-api.solscan.io/pro-api-docs/v1.0.

Actually, I want to fillter the accounts' transfers at websocket or https. when I use logsSubscribe at ws, there is only one public key can be set up, but we have a lot of accounts. and then I want to subscribe accountSubscribe topic at ws, but I don't know how many ws colections can be keep at sametime.

If someone had the experience as me, please answer me, it's very urgent! thanks so so much!

Answer (score 0):

You might use use map and an array of public key strings to listen to many tens of thousands at one time

```
const publicKeyStrings = [...]

const publicKeys = publicKeyStrings.map((pubKeyStr) => new PublicKey(pubKeyStr));

publicKeys.map(async (publicKey) => {
  connection.onAccountChange(publicKey, async (accountInfo) => {
    const balance = accountInfo.lamports;
    console.log(balance, publicKey)
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your kind answer!  Your example could listened the change of balance, but couldn't get the detail transaction that from another acount or sent by itself. I hope that I can know the account's transactions. like a tx scanner.

Comment: On the callback you might try to have it call getSignaturesForAddress, {limit: 1}, then getParsedTransaction on that and you'll have the latest transactions details